# Question in the lecture of Lineare algebra done right, exemple of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Can sombothy explain why the set of differentiable real-valued functions $f$ on the interval $(0,3)$ such that $f'(2)= b$ is a subspace of $R^{(0,3)}$ if and only if $b = 0$.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $b$ is not equal to $0$, then for two elements $f,g \in R^{(0,3)}$ we would have for the differential of an element $(f+g)'(2) = f'(2) + g'(2) = 2b \neq b$, so $f+g \not\in R^{(0,3)}$, then it would not be a subspace.

On the other hand, one can show that for $b=0$ the subspace criterions are satisfied.

Comment: Or perhaps simpler: if $\;b\neq0\;$ then the vector zero (i.e., the zero function) is not in that set...

Comment: That was a fast and clear answer thanks

Comment: @NicolasLussier-Clément: No problem, glad it helped! Thanks for accepting my answer!

Comment: Oups i have made a error in my question it was about the derivatibe of $f$ but your answer is still valid.